# Looking for an explanation regarding file.delete() method in try catch block

Tags: java

Trying to make a simple 'cut' program to move files across folders.
After it makes a copy it should delete the source file but it ignores the fileLocation.delete(); method in the try block. If I put it in the 'finally' block it works and also anywhere else in the program after it goes through copying the file but that makes no sense for it to work that way, even if something goes wrong the source will be deleted. My question is why does it ignore it, I was unable to find answers online. Thank you.

```
    File fileLocation = new File("C:\\fileLocation\\picture.png");
    File fileDestination = new File("C:\\fileDestination\\picture.png");

    try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileDestination)) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer,0, length);
        }

        fileLocation.delete();

    } catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try(FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
    ... ) {
  // ..

  fileLocation.delete();
}
```

At this point, `input` is still open, so you can't delete the file it refers to.

According to [the definition of try-with-resources in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), a `finally` block on a try-with-resources statement will be executed after the resource is closed. As such, putting the delete in the `finally` block means it can succeed.

---

Rather than putting it in the `finally` (which occurs whether or not an exception is thrown), you can split up the resources into two try-with-resources blocks, and delete once you're done with `input`:

```
try (FileOutputStream output = ...) {
  try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileLocation)) {
    // ..
  }

  // input is now closed.
  fileLocation.delete();
} catch(IOException exc) {
  System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
}
```

Now, `fileLocation` is only deleted when no `IOException` is thrown from any preceding statement in the `output` try-with-resources block (including the `input` try-with-resources block).

Or, if you want not to delete it until `output` is closed: move the `IOException` catch into a surrounding try/catch (not try-with-resources) block:

```
try {
  try (FileOutputStream output = ...;
       FileInputStream input = ...) {
    // ..
  }

  // input and output are now both closed.
  fileLocation.delete();
} catch(IOException exc) {
  System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
}
```

---

Of course, a better way to move a file would be to use [the utility method to move files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)), e.g.

```
Files.move(fileLocation.toPath(), fileDestination.toPath(), CopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: Only after the output is written successfully, one should delete the closed input. A bit careful coding. Or simply use Files.move.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong API. `File.delete()` is known-bad API design.

This is what's bad about it, and why it explains your confusion: Unlike just about any other API, if `delete()` fails to delete, it **does not** throw any exceptions. Instead, it returns `false`. This is bad in 3 important ways:

- It's un-java-like. Very few APIs do that; the vast majority of them throw something instead.
- It is easy to 'forget'. Just writing `x.foo();` on its own, where `foo()` is any method that returns something (i.e. has a non-`void` return type), is perfectly fine java. it's java-ese for: Run this method, then take the result and toss it in the garbage. You've done that here: Call `delete()` and ignore the result. For delete(), that's not actually okay unless you intended to write code that effectively means: "**try** to delete this path. Whether it succeeds or not, continue with the code". Which, usually, isn't what you want.
- If something *does* go wrong, it is **not possible** for the `delete()` method to tell you any details other than 'I could not accomplish it'. No way to have a message or some sort of exception type to clear things up for you.

The solution is simple. Stop using this method. Put it on the banlist: This method should no longer ever be invoked in java code. If you are maintaining some 15 year old stuff, it's fine, I guess, but a quick refactor to get rid of it wouldn't go amiss.

### Great! So what's the new one I should be using?

The path/files API in the `java.nio.file` package.

Replace:

```
File f = new File("a/b/c.txt");
f.delete();
```

with:

```
Path p = Paths.get("a/b/c.txt");
Files.delete(p);
```

Unlike `file.delete()`, `Files.delete(path)` WILL throw an exception if the deletion cannot be performed. This exception then contains suitable information about why. For example, because the file doesn't exist, or because you do not have write access to the underlying directory, or because the file system is mounted read only, etcetera.

The new File API is also vastly more capable. It can properly handle links or alternate file systems, for example. It also has more methods. For example, it has the `Files.move` method which may be of particular use here.

### Just for reference, why is my delete operation failing?

Probably because your own process still has the file open. On some OS/filesystem combos (in particular, on windows and e.g. NTFS), you can't delete open files. Even if your own process is the one that still has the file open.

If you use Files.delete() you'll get an exception with a message that'll get you a lot closer to that conclusion than 'the `delete()` call returned `false`', fortunately.